# Should I use boolean or Boolean in a Spring Boot RestController?

Tags: spring-boot

Make it any difference to use in the following snippet **boolean** filterMode or **Boolean** filterMode? Are they any best practice ?
Or its completley irrelevant?

```
@GetMapping
public NOTMATTER getResultByBoolean(
 @RequestParam(value = "filterMode", required = false) boolean filterMode) {

  //.....

}
```

Comment: I see that parameter is not required. I suggest you to try calling that endpoint without that parameter. Try it with `Boolean`, then try it with `boolean` and see the different behaviors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will matter. As you have specified the parameter to be optional, if it is not supplied then default values will be different

```
// Boolean - default value is null
// boolean - default value is false
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the type boolean and the type Boolean.

- **boolean** is a primitive type that can accept the values true or false
- **Boolean** is an Object that wraps the value of a boolean primitive. It exposes more actions that can be performed on the type.

I suggest you read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).

The usage depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case. If you're sure that it's acceptable to have the false value as a default one (judging by your code, I think that this is your case) then go for the primitive `boolean` type. It consumes a lot less memory in comparison with objects and provides the default false value, so there would be no need for setting `required = false` for your request parameter.

However, it may lead to unpredicted behavior for your clients. Just imagine the case with parameters like `opt in` or `opt out` for a messaging system, which identifies if a client wants to stop communication with some service. There would be a significant difference between the null and the false value for these parameters, which may lead to legal consequences for your company. So it's better to be careful with a such choice.